# Query optimization with rows referring to parents

Tags: sql

I have one table that has "Id", "ParentId", and "CreatedDate". If the row is an original submission, it will have no "ParentId". When an edit is made to an original submission, a new row is created where NewRow."ParentId" = Original."Id". Every new edit made from there on will take the proper "ParentId". This gives a way to see the history of edits.

Now for the query. I rushed together a query that will get all of the latest and unique entries. For example. if I have 3 unique original forms. I only want to see their most recent revision (most recent child) unless they have none, in which case I want the original where "ParentId" IS NULL.

This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.* 
FROM   "dbo"."customercomplaint" AS A 
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN "dbo"."customercomplaint" AS B 
                     ON B."parentid" != A."id" 
WHERE  A."parentid" IS NULL 
       AND A."id" IS NOT NULL 
UNION 
SELECT t1.* 
FROM   "dbo"."customercomplaint" t1 
       JOIN (SELECT "parentid"         AS id, 
                    Max("createddate") AS "CreatedDate" 
             FROM   "dbo"."customercomplaint" 
             GROUP  BY id) t2 
         ON t1."parentid" = t2.id 
            AND t1."createddate" = t2."createddate"
```

This query feels a little sloppy to me and I would like to seek out a better solution. Let me know if any further information is required. I appreciate any and all advice.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`?

Comment: If you have two edits, will both of them have the same parentid or will you have a 3 level hierarchy?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO UNION ALL will return duplicates.

Comment: @JoaoLeal Yes, both of them will refer to the same parentId.

Comment: Then the answer below should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the query using Row_Number() function.

Below is an example and a [working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c13b2/1)

```
select ID, ParentID, CreatedDate
from (
        select ID, ParentID, CreatedDate, row_number() over(partition by isnull(ParentID, ID) order by CreatedDate desc) RowNumber
        from CustomerComplaint
   ) t
 where
    t.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: This is awesome. As I am using PostgreSQL, I will need to use coalesce instead of isnull. Now I just need to figure out how to convert it to LINQ. Thank you for your help.